# Is there any way to use ssh to open remote windows from a raspberry pi to a Windows 10 machine?

Tags: windows, ssh, raspberry-pi

We have students running windows 10. They install msys2 to do linux development, but could try to install wsl. In the past, wsl had everything except graphics, now it has graphics as well, but I do not believe it is a full xwindow implementation.

Is there any way to get the command:

```
ssh -Y pi@192.168.1.99
```

to work where the client is running windows, without paying for a proprietary xwindow implementation for windows?

If not, our fallback is vnc, which isn't bad, but ssh is sometimes more convenient.

Comment: You don't need msys2  or WSL2.  Just install the optional OpenSSH Client. WSL only has graphics on Windows 11.

Comment: Are you install xrdp server on Linux side. Then Windows users can connect using rdp client which is included in all Windows versions.

Answer (score 1):

> In the past, wsl had everything except graphics, now it has graphics as well, but I do not believe it is a full xwindow implementation.

WSLg is primarily a *Wayland* implementation (or rather a bridge between Wayland and RDP), but it [also supports](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps#install-x11-apps) X11 clients according to its official documentation.

Most likely it achieves X11 support by running the Xwayland bridge within WSL – Xwayland itself is developed as part of Xorg, and is already used to provide X11 compatibility in GNOME, KDE, and other Wayland-based Linux desktop environments.

> without paying for a proprietary xwindow implementation for windows?

By using freely available ones, then. The Xorg project actually includes an X server for Windows (called XWin), which can be installed [through Cygwin](https://x.cygwin.com/). Several other "non-paid" products exist, most of them likely derived from Xorg – so far I've found Xming and VcxSrv, I'm sure there are more.